# Spring AOP AspectJ trying to advise classes that don't match pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

I have an AOP log setup in one project that's not working in another.

From build.gradle:

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.2.RELEASE" 
[...]
compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.10"
compile "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.10"
```

I have a base aspect to log around some APIs:

```
@Aspect
public abstract class Profiler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    protected abstract void toLog();   

    @Around("toLog()")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {

[...]
```

I have derived classes to define pointcuts:

```
@Aspect
public class SDKProfiler extends Profiler {
    @Override
    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.company.app.stuff.*.*(..))")
    protected void toLog() {}
}
```

I have enabled aspecjtJ with @EnableAspectJAutoProxy on my configuration.
When I try to load the ConfigurableApplicationContext in main, I end up with this exception:

```
[...]  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut toLog
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:170)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:220)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:279)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:311)
    [...]
```

This happens while Spring is trying to autowire a class that doesn't in anyway match the pointcut expression.  If I remove that bean, it will fail in the same way against another bean that doesn't match the pointcut expression.  Looking at previous questions, I've seen people having success by upgrading their version of AspectJ. As of this writing, that's not an option since 1.8.10 is current latest version.

This code works properly in a similar application where the only obvious difference is the build tool, maven.  However, there's no compile time weaving going on, so that shouldn't be a factor.

Any idea why spring is trying to find a 'toLog' pointcut in 3rd party classes that don't match the expression?

Comment: What's the point of subclassing an `Aspect`? If you want to apply the same treatment to multiple join points, you just make a `private` method.

Comment: Sure, this could have been structured differently.   Any idea about why the weaver is looking for the "toLog" pointcut in (what seems like) random classes?

Comment: my comment was not only about code structuring. You've set up the base class as an aspect, as well as the subclass, but only the subclass has a join point. Your design could very well be the reason for the weird behavior.

Comment: This is working in another project.   I did try moving all annotations to the derived class.   No luck; same behavior.

Comment: Ok, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll take a look. As it stands, you didn't show the classes that you expect to be picked up and those that don't. Based on your comment that the "same" setup works elsewhere, there could be other variables. We need to see code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something salient was different between the original project and the new project.  The new project added the aspects to the context via a configuration class whereas the old (working) project added the aspects via component scan.  Switching to component scan of the aspects fixed the problem.
Bad:

```
@Configuration
public class LoggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public SDKProfiler sdkProfiler() { return new SDKProfiler(); }
}
```

Good:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.company.app.logging")
public class LoggerConfig {
}
```

Where the aspects are in the com.company.app.logging package.

Thanks Abhijit for taking the time to reply.  I really thought I'd considered everything different between the projects prior to posting.